# Get dataframe from two different function and write in into two different excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to Python, I have two functions func1 and func2, where I have one dataframe in each function.
I'd want to get the df1 from func1 to be written on sheet1 and df2 from func2 to be written on same excel but sheet2.
I have tried individual excelwriter inside each function that does write the records but the func2 overwrites the Df1 with Df2, thats why I am trying to get both the df outside and trying to write one after other, So I am also having trouble calling the df outside the function.
I cannot send my project query, pasting sample query, any help/suggestion would be appreciated.
FYI this query is showing error.

```
import pandas as pd

def func1():

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Andreas', 'George', 'Steve',
                        'Sarah', 'Joanna', 'Hanna'],
                        'Age':[21, 22, 20, 19, 18, 23]})
                        
    adf1 = return df1                                     

func1()

def func2(df2):

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Pete', 'Jordan', 'Gustaf',
                    'Sophie', 'Sally', 'Simone'],
                    'Age':[22, 21, 19, 19, 29, 21]})

    adf2 = return df2        
 
func2()      

Filepath='C:/Users/kharikrishnan/xlopt/bb10.xlsx'    
writer= pd.ExcelWriter(Filepath) 

df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False,startrow=0, startcol=0) 
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet2',index=False,startrow=10, startcol=0) 
writer.save() 
writer.close()
```

Comment: What error ? share it

Comment: It seems that you are not familiar with variables in the function, how to access them and how return works at the end of function. I would suggest you to research more about it and you will get your answer yourself

Comment: @j Yes, I am a Datawarehousing professional trying to automate some of testing in out project, I am very new to programming itself, will work on learning those. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use functions, if you aren't doing anything with dataframes inside them (like in example). In this case, try this:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Andreas', 'George', 'Steve',
                              'Sarah', 'Joanna', 'Hanna'],
                    'Age':[21, 22, 20, 19, 18, 23]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Pete', 'Jordan', 'Gustaf',
                              'Sophie', 'Sally', 'Simone'],
                    'Age':[22, 21, 19, 19, 29, 21]})

filepath = 'C:/Users/kharikrishnan/xlopt/bb10.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath) 

df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False,startrow=0, startcol=0) 
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet2',index=False,startrow=10, startcol=0) 
writer.save() 
writer.close()
```

[TIP] Try to use lowercase names for variables (not `Filepath` but `filepath`). [More information how to write nice code in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

If you processing the dataframes with the functions you have to just `return` the result. What's more, just calling the functions doing nothing here, you have to assign it to a variable. Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Andreas', 'George', 'Steve',
                              'Sarah', 'Joanna', 'Hanna'],
                    'Age':[21, 22, 20, 19, 18, 23]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Pete', 'Jordan', 'Gustaf',
                              'Sophie', 'Sally', 'Simone'],
                    'Age':[22, 21, 19, 19, 29, 21]})


def func1(dataframe):
    # some processes using dataframe, i. e. adding new column:
    dataframe['new_col'] = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', ]
    return dataframe                                     


def func2(dataframe):
    processed_dataframe = <some another processes using dataframe>
    return processed_dataframe        


new_df1 = func1(df1)
new_df1 = func1(df2)

filepath = 'C:/Users/kharikrishnan/xlopt/bb10.xlsx'    
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath) 

new_df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False,startrow=0, startcol=0) 
new_df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet2',index=False,startrow=10, startcol=0) 
writer.save() 
writer.close()
```

I hope it'll help you. Ask, if you don't understand something.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, I will follow your suggestion.
That was just  a sample code, the reason I need two functions cause I am connecting to two different databases in those two functions, in each function the dataframe reads data from table and holds content of an query..
Can you help like If I have more than two data frame returning in from two functions and have it printed on excel, Meanwhile I am searching, but If you can help, it would be great, thanks :)

Comment: @TheKrish0229, i. e. in `function()`: `return dataframe1, dataframe2`. Then: `df1, df2 = function()` and you can use it as before.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you retrieve element from a method, just use a `return` and store it (frmo the method call) in a variable that you can use after

```
def func1():
    return pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Andreas', 'George', 'Steve',
                                   'Sarah', 'Joanna', 'Hanna'],
                         'Age': [21, 22, 20, 19, 18, 23]})

def func2():
    return pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Pete', 'Jordan', 'Gustaf',
                                   'Sophie', 'Sally', 'Simone'],
                         'Age': [22, 21, 19, 19, 29, 21]})


df1 = func1()
df2 = func2()

Filepath = 'C:/Users/kharikrishnan/xlopt/bb10.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Filepath)

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow=0, startcol=0)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False, startrow=10, startcol=0)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Note that here, `df1` is written in one sheet, and `df2` is written in another sheet with a 10 rows top padding

Comment: There is no need to use functions to just returning the dataframes.

Comment: @maciejwww : Yes you are right, this is a snippet to show the gist of my requirement.

Comment: @maciejwww of course it could be inlined, But if I did that, it wouldn't have explained to the OP how to use the returned content from a method ;)